# Update Record by using ajax in Entity Framework MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4, asp.net-ajax

I am beginner and trying to update my record by using **Ajax call** in **Entity Framework MVC**. I am getting `idtoSearch` successfully but not getting `std.FirstName` and `std.LastName` at controller side. As you can see in my code here

## AjaxStudentController

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStudent(Student std, int idtoSearch) {
    using (StudentContext db = new StudentContext()) {
     Student updatestd = db.Student.Find(idtoSearch);
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(std.FirstName)) { updatestd.FirstName = std.FirstName; }
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(std.LastName)) { updatestd.LastName = std.LastName; }
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
       return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

and here you can see ajax code

```
<button class='upbtn' data-upid=" + stdid + ">Update</button>    
$(".upbtn").click(function () {
                        var student = {
                         "upFirstName" : $("#name").val(),
                         "upLastName" : $("#lname").val(),
                        }
                       $.ajax({
                           url: "/AjaxStudent/UpdateStudent",
                           method: "Post",
                           data: {
                               idtoSearch: upid,
                               std: student
                           }
                        }).done(function(){
                                alert("Update button");
                           }).
                           error(function () {
                               alert("Update Error");
                           });
                    });
```

I am unable to get any update at browser. Anybody please tell me what should I do.

Comment: Is your ajax call returning a 200 OK response ? Check your browser dev tools. Are you getting any of the alerts ?

Comment: Where is `upid` variable defined or initialized ?

Comment: @Shyju I am Getting **Update button** at browser and `upid` is initialized in Update button

Comment: So what is not working ? If you see "Update button", that means your ajax call received 200 OK from your action method call. What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: I want to see updated values at browser.

Comment: Do you have a details action/view ? If yes navigate to it. Or you can have your action method return the object (instead of `true` and you can update your UI inside the `done` method

Comment: Also, where in the browser ?

Comment: You already have the data in the browser (that is what you sent using ajax), What else you want to display then ?

Comment: Yes, I have data there. Actually, I want to update the student's first name and last name  which is already in browser.

Comment: So what is not working ? I am still not following what your expected behavior is. You have the data in the browser. What to update now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174602/discussion-between-nabia-saroosh-and-shyju).

Comment: Your not sending the data in the correct format. If you want to send a complex object and another object, then you need `data: JSON.stringify({ idtoSearch: upid, std: student })` and you need to add the `contentType: 'application/json'` option. But your property names do not even seem to match - your model has a property `FirstName`, but you sending a value for a property named `upFirstName`

Comment: It's a valid point I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem. I was updating my data in wrong variable i.e. `upFirstName` & `upLastName`. That was my mistake. I should update my data in same variable i.e. `FirstName` & `LastName`. Just write below code

```
var student = {
       "FirstName" : $("#name").val(),
       "LastName" : $("#lname").val(),
}
```

Instead of this

```
var student = {
        "upFirstName" : $("#name").val(),
        "upLastName" : $("#lname").val(),
  }
```

I hope it's will be helpful for you also.